# Dynamic Data - show properties in the metadata class only

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dynamic-data

In Dynamic Data, we can control what columns are shown using the `ScaffoldColumnAttribute` and the `AutoGenerateField` property of the `DisplayAttribute`.

Right now, I need to decorate the properties in my metadata classes one by one (I am using EF database first approach). And the problem is that I have an ever-changing model.

Is there any way to show only those properties defined in my metadata classes? That is - if the property is in the metadata class, do show, otherwise hide. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I based my work on this Steve's fine article:

http://csharpbits.notaclue.net/2008/05/introduction-this-project-is-going-to.html

Thank you.